# Explicit Riemann mappings

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Typical proofs of the [Riemann mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) are not terribly explicit (one maximizes a functional, or something equivalent, such as using [Dirichlet's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_principle)).

The theorem states that if $U$ is a simply connected open subset of the plane, then there is a biholomorphism between $U$ and the unit disk. I imagine, due to the wild generality of the result, no explicit construction can be expected in general. However, in many concrete cases, I would think a construction "by hand" should be possible; and in applications (to problems in engineering, for example), this would almost be a requirement.

Do you know of such a construction, or of a reference where these constructions are discussed? (The answer may of course only apply to certain families of open sets.)

I know of a very nice reference: "Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping", by Tobin A. Driscoll and Lloyd N. Trefethen, Cambridge Monographs on Applied and Computational Mathematics (No. 8). The [Schwarz-Christoffel Mappings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping) explicitly give us biholomorphisms between the upper half plane and the interior of *simple polygons*. I am hoping for additional examples.

Comment: Google for the [Schwarz-Christoffel formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz–Christoffel_mapping) and keep your favorite manual on elliptic integrals handy.

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks! I actually have been working through "Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping" by Driscoll and Lloyd (http://www.cambridge.org/cz/knowledge/isbn/item1169156/?site_locale=cs_CZ) It is what inspired the question. (I'll edit the body of the question to reflect this.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a very big question, and a lot of work has been done on making the Riemann mapping theorem more explicit.  I have several comments:

1. [Böttcher coordinates](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~buff/Preprints/Bottcher/Bottcher.pdf) provide explicit Riemann maps for the Fatou component containing a superattracting fixed point for a rational map.  In particular, a Riemann map for the complement of the [filled Julia set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filled_Julia_set) of a quadratic polynomial with connected Julia set can be computed fairly explicitly.  Similarly, the Riemann map for the complement of the [Mandelbrot set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) is fairly explicitly computable.
2. Thurston and others have done some beautiful work involving approximating arbitrary Riemann maps using [circle packings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing).  See [*Circle Packing: A Mathematical Tale*](http://www.ams.org/notices/200311/fea-stephenson.pdf) by Stephenson.
3. To some extent, constructing a Riemann map is simply a matter of constructing a [harmonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) on a given domain (as well as the associated [harmonic conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate)), subject to certain boundary conditions.  The solution to such problems is a huge topic of research in the study of PDE's, although the connection with Riemann maps is rarely mentioned.

**Edit:** Incidentally, if I wanted to construct a Riemann map explicitly on a given domain $D$, I would use the following PDE's approach.  First, translate the domain so that it contains the origin.  Next, use a numerical method to construct a harmonic function $F$ satisfying
$$
F(z) \;=\; -\log |z|
$$
for all $z\in\partial D$, and let
$$
R(z) = |z|e^{F(z)}.
$$
Then $R(0) = 0$, $R|_{\partial D} \equiv 1$, and $\log R$ is harmonic, so $R$ is the  radial component (i.e. modulus) of a Riemann map on $D$. The angular component can now be determined by the fact that its level curves are perpendicular to the level curves of $R$, and have equal angular spacing near the origin.

Comment: Many thanks for this fantastic answer!